# A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running

Tags: olap-cube, sql-server-2012-express, sqlbrowser

When I am trying to process dimensions after creating a data source view I get the error:

> The project could not be deployed to the server because of the following connectivity problems :  A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running.  To verify or update the name of the target server, right-click on the project in Solution Explorer, select Project Properties,click on the Deployment tab, and then enter the name of the server.

I have checked in task manager & SQLBrowser is running. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: 1. Follow instructions in Link:http://jandho.blogspot.com/2014/10/analysis-services-2012-connection.html
2. Click on Allow an app or feature through Windows Firewall
3. Identify the name of the connection created in Step 1, then make sure Domain, Private and Public checkboxes are checked for the connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get the SQL Server instances on my computer this way:

1. Start Menu
2. Microsoft SQL Server 2008 or your version
3. Server Installation Center
4. Admin login
5. Select "Tools" from left menu
6. Select "Installed SQL Server features discovery report"

You then get a nice HTML web page.  You want to look for Database Services.  You should see an instance name.  Mine is called "SQLEXPRESS."  So the combination of server name and instance would be **MYCOMPUTER\SQLEXPRESS** given that my computer name is MYCOMPUTER.

BTW, the default instance name is **MSSQLSERVER**.

Alternatively, you can get it from your registry.  Just run regedit and look for this key: **Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL**

Answer (score 1):

Check that the SQL Server service itself (or MSSQLSERVER) is running.  Also check the connection string.

> If you want to deploy the project to a named instance of Analysis Services on the local computer, or to an instance on a remote server, change the Server property to the appropriate instance name, such as <InstanceName>.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/multidimensional-tutorial/lesson-2-5-deploying-an-analysis-services-project?view=asallproducts-allversions

You need the server name and the instance name.

Comment: SQL server is running. what is the server name i should give  while deploying the project? @Charles Owen

Comment: Are you deploying this locally or to a remote server?

Comment: local @Charles Owen

Answer (score 0):

Open port 2382,2383 to server solve this issue for me.